# Why is my model creating edges when exporting to another format?

Tags: mesh, export, edit-mode, edges, 3d-printing

So when I'm exporting my model to an .stl for 3D printing, it creates these strange edges within the model. The edges aren't present when in edit mode so I'm unsure to why this might be happening.
I've already tried remodeling it twice but somehow these edges keep occurring even though there is no history of them ever being there. Another thing to note is that whenever I use the re-mesh modifier with the object, the edges appear then as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Original Model in edit mode:

[image: Original Model in edit mode]

Model after exporting to .stl:

[image: Model after exporting to .stl:]

Comment: Difficult to say just from images. Please share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there so that we can have a look at the object.

Comment: @JohnEason That's not necessary. The simple reason is, meshes from STL files (and other formats) cannot have quads, every face will be triangulated. And depending on the shading etc. they can look strange.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Fair enough, but being able to see the actual topology might allow folks to suggest a workaround.

Comment: @JohnEason Maybe, but it will not change the fact that STL only accepts triangles. And to be honest, when I'm exporting something to STL the reason is usually that I don't want to proceed with the object in Blender - so I wouldn't care how it looks there anyway.